# Copy a file from HDFS to a local directory for multiple tasks on a node?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, bigdata

So, basically, I have a read only file (several GBs big, so broadcasting is no option) that must be copied to a local folder on the node, as each task internally runs a program (by using os.system in python or ! operator in scala) that reads from a local file (can't read from HDFS). The problem however is that several tasks would be running on one node. If the file is not already there on the node, it should be copied from the HDFS to a local directory. But how could I have one task get the file from the HDFS, while other tasks wait for it (note that each task would be running in parallel on a node). Which file synchronization mechanism could I use in Spark for that purpose?

Comment: why you ever need to copy file to local node? if your Spark executors run on the same hosts that HDFS DataNodes, Spark should keep data locality by detecting which split have to be loaded to executor. Another option is to distribute file across executors using spark.yarn.dist.files in YARN mode

Comment: Like I said, a task internally executes a program (os.system stuff in python or ! operator in scala). That program reads files from local directories (it can't read from HDFS). That is why I need to copy the file to the local directory first.

Comment: Ok, you're still able to use second option, with spark.yarn.dist.files you will have your file in your executors' working directories

Comment: But does that mean each executor would have to copy the file separately. I don't want that either. As I would have a lot of tasks running, and needlessly copying the file again and again would be really bad for the performance.

Comment: YARN should use hadoop distributed cache for this, so once file will be copied to YARN's node, no copy will be needed next time - only symbolic link creation. I can't check this right now, but I guess this approach is worse trying.

Comment: I hope so. Thanks for telling :).